# Scraping with CasperJS/PhantomJs

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I want to scrap some data with CasperJS from one popular site. I have already scraped successfully some data with pool of proxies. Now I'm worried about HTTP REQUEST headers, coming with my HTTP Request. 
I know there a lot information about me, and my servers - so is there exist some way to delete or modify outgoing HTTP headers.

Comment: Any proxy may do that, eg. squid http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_replace/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom headers to casperjs with the headers property. You should be able to alter headers that you are concerned about.

Example: http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper

```
casper.open('http://some.testserver.com/post.php', {
    method: 'post',
    data:   {
       'title': 'Plop',
        'body':  'Wow.'
    },
    headers: {
       'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3'
    }
});
```